# Callbacks in pr2 controllers

Tags: ros, pr2-controllers, pr2, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ros answers users,

I'm currently trying to make a custom controller work on pr2. I have two subscribers inside the controller.My problem is that their respective callbacks are not called. Moreover I noticed that the existing controllers on pr2 (namely joint_spline_controller and joint_velocity_controller ) don't call spinOnce. Still, they use subscribers and callbacks.
So my question is how and when are callbacks called for a controller ?

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9383/callbacks-in-pr2-controllers/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guido,

ROS's `spin()` function is called external to the controller manager.  On the PR2, it's called from pr2_etherCAT, and in Gazebo it's called from pr2_gazebo_plugins.  The controller manager itself uses ROS to load and unload controllers, and many other topics are published (such as joint_state), so if `spin()` weren't being called, there would be many other issues.

I'm not sure why your subscription callback isn't being called, but I suspect it's just related to standard ROS issues and unrelated to the controllers.  Try using `rostopic info`, `rostopic echo`, `rosnode ping`, and `rosnode info`.  Check that both ends are connected to the same topic, and that messages are being published.

One last thing to check: be sure that your controller's `init()` method finishes.

If you still can't find the issue, try posting some code.

Best of luck

---

Originally posted by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) with karma: 649 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-03-23**:
It was indeed a connection problem between both ends of the topic. I forgot to take into account namespaces, so the topic advertised was /command but the topic to which I should publish is /my_controller/command. I was missing the "/my_controller" part. Thank you for the explanation.